# How come this code is unable to provide smooth CSS3 scrolling when on-click?

Tags: html, css

I was following a YouTube tutorial on how to do `CSS3` `smooth scrolling` to `DIV` but somehow I was unable to replicate that result onto my piece of `side-navbar`.

`index.html` and `style.css`

```css
    .sidenav {
        height: 100vh; 
        width: 0; 
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 1; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111; 
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        padding-top: 60px; 
        transition: 0.5s;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#" id="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#resume">Resume</a>
        <a href="#media">Media</a>
</div>
```

How come?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or a snippet?

Comment: You want the `scroll-behavior` rule on the thing that scrolls (html or body), not on the fixed-position navbar.

Comment: Also please add an example of the required behavior (and maybe the link to the Youtube video)

Comment: Where's your `closeNav` function?